# CVS Beginner ,need software

Tags: untagged

I am a CVS beginner i want to begin to use it

I read a lot about CVS and what it do

As i read i found that i need two software CVS server and CVS client

What is the best free software i can use on linux and windows and how can i find a way to use it?

i knew about [smartCVS](http://www.syntevo.com/smartcvs/index.html) but it is a client how can i find a server

Comment: You set one up yourself.

Comment: i do not understand you lucas 

there is free softwares make cvs clients and server i want to know the best and how to use it

Comment: Sorry refer to the FaQ, questions about the "best" products is off-topic. I would like to refer you to try and search on google.

Comment: i did and i find smartcvs and tortoisecva but really i do not understand if they are clients or servers and if i exactly need a server and client? google say yes programs say no what is the right?

Comment: It's a CVS client. It says so on the first page: SmartCVS is an innovative CVS client

Comment: Step one of using CVS: look into Git instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better forget about CVS, it is mostly legacy now. A more modern centralized version control system in the same line is SVN ([subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/)), designed as a better CVS and to replace it. And it (almost) suceeded.

But today most version control systems are [distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_revision_control), see also Joel Spolsky's [blog](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/03/17.html)
on the matter. Distributed systems are easier to handle, more robust and featureful. One big plus is that one can set them up for purely local, personal use, or use them to share and work together with others. The most popular open source ones are [git](http://www.git-scm.com), developed for and used by the Linux kernel, many more large, visible open source projects use it now; hg ([mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/)) is reported to be easier to use than git, and also quite popular, written in Python it is supposed to run better on Windows (I can't comment, long-time Linux-only); the third contender is bzr ([bazaar](http://bazaar.canonical.com/)), that is the distributed version control system selected by Canonical for use in their infrastructure for the Ubuntu distribution, but almost nobody else uses it.

There are many free repository hosting services that handle your projects, shop around if you need one.